# Simulate Metered Connections in Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, simulator

I'm having a little trouble working out how to simulate a metered connection over a **wired** network (can be on local machine or the simulator).

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer was to test the app on another device using a **wireless** connection which you can then set as metered.

Comment: Dumb question, but set as metered where? Is this something you do in the app or Visual Studio, on the other device, or somewhere else? Thanks!

Comment: @Stonetip: It's a property of the connection itself.  In the networks sidebar, right click on the network and choose "Set as metered connection"

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaFrank! Yes, it's unfortunate there's not another way, but at least for those with wireless devices it works.

Comment: I'm sure this is obvious, but you could also add a Dependency Injection layer between your app and the network, and ask it for the connection.  It could then do various things to simulate a metered connection, like keep track of how much bandwidth it's using and notify you when you've used too much, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We asked about this at an AEL and were told that there's no way to simulate it.  You just have to trust that the value of

```
Windows.Networking.Connectivity.DataPlanStatus.MaxTransferSizeInMegabytes
```

will be correct.